# Are these buttons disabled? I think they're disabled. They're disabled, aren't they? These buttons are disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Are these buttons disabled?

> [image]

I think they're disabled.

> [image]

They're disabled, aren't they?

> [image]

These buttons are disabled.

y tho?

Comment: Huh? None of those buttons are disabled. Do you mean the greyed-out color looks like a disabled button? Because all these toggles are just grey, not greyed-out

Comment: (They look exactly like disabled buttons should look. They're not disabled, they shouldn't be looking that way. Design bug imho)

Comment: Designers tend to be mac-jockeys, [it doesn't work that way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5715092/17034).

Comment: I see you've been trying to "which of these google" your question title. Nice try but no cigar. I'm thoroughly +1 on the *delightful* free hand red art forms however.

Comment: But are the buttons disabled?

Comment: But... Are you disabled? Your badge and name in the comments has an oddly greyed-out look here.

Comment: My badge isn't a button. [My hair, however, is a bird, therefore your argument is invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGXMJ.png), @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: You're not supposed to click at an "already selected" option right? So what's wrong?

Comment: All the buttons appear to be disabled. All of them. Even the one with pseudo-focus.

Comment: Someone watched 50 shades of grey, then decided to work on the redesign. (I mean that in all possible interpretations)

Comment: @user202729 Oh, also, clicking on an "already selected" option *is* a completely valid action, and it works right now. Doing so refreshes the list of questions. Common workflow.

Comment: The buttons are disabled. I know because my gut instinct tells me so.

Comment: Side note, the total # of q's rolled over to 16m while I was composing this question...

Comment: @Will What color would you suggest these buttons be? Feel free to fire up inspector and offer a solution.

Comment: I offered a few solutions to this problem. Feel free to offer your solution and/or upvote/downvote one of my solutions.

Comment: I have the same confusion with Tools/Reviews on the Reviews page...

Comment: Your artwork speaks to me on an emotional level; do you accept commissioned work?

Comment: Why, yes, I do. The first one is always free. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBotH.png

Comment: Yasssss, that's the stuff!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for providing this feedback. The design team recently identified the filter selected state as an area that needed improving. We also thought it communicated a "disabled" state when it should communicate the opposite: it's selected! Your post serves as a great reminder that we need to start implementing our solution.

We will be updating the filter selected state to look like this now:

[image: Updated filter style]

Thanks for your patience. This should be implemented in the next day or so.

Comment: The "active" and "more," being lightish gray, still look to me like they could be disabled.

Comment: I don't think this _very_ minor change helps the situation at all.

Answer (score 27):

Another possible solution is `AskQuestionBlue` color, which comes from that blue `Ask Question` button:

[image]

Comment: This mostly makes me realize how off the blue for bounties is from that other blue…

Answer (score -11):

One possible solution is to color them in `StackOverflowOrange`, as it appears to be the "accent" color:

[image]

Comment: Oh, please don't use that orange, whatever you do

Comment: @AlonEitan I don't like it neither. I am 100% OK with grey buttons because I **know** those buttons are not disabled. I am just trying to offer solution.

Comment: @AlonEitan wait, are you saying that we don't only have to chose between enabled and disabled but we can also chose an orange? If not that orange, which other orange can I choose? Or is black the new orange? Man, this is confusing stuff ...

Comment: Oh boy, this is becoming more and more like an art project :D

Comment: I'm hoping the SO frontend devs implement the red hand-drawn line too, maybe as an SVG or Canvas image. Perhaps we can even have a drawing Easter-egg?

Comment: @halfer That's a good April 1st joke.

Comment: @AlexL: surely users will want to draw Wow! circles all year round? `:-p`

Answer (score -22):

It's OK for those buttons being grey color because:

1. People who use StackOverflow frequently know what those buttons do and they know that they are not disabled.
2. For those who are new to this site: it's not hard to click a button and find out whether it is disabled or not.
3. Grey background appears on hover, which indicates that button is clickable.

Comment: While people may learn that this buttons may not be disabled, the low gray contrast on the button is very similar to a typical disabled button. Some color contrast with the copy and border would help dispel this idea.

Comment: Also, to @Will's main point: the selected state here looks a lot like what a disabled, outlined button would look like on Stack: https://stackoverflow.design/components/buttons#secondary

Comment: Ooooo. I'm gonna keep an eye on that repo.

Comment: Oh wow! You've got your won full-fledged bootstrap there. Cool!